# A Bash script with parameter output

Tags: shell

> I have the task to do this
>
> Write a shell script evenparam.sh which has an even number of command line >parameters, so it has the syntax
>   evenparam.sh para1 para2 [para3 para4] ...
>   The script should generate an output of the form para1 = para2, para3 = >para4, ....
>   Issue a usage message on stderr and finish the script with a return value >of 1 if the program was not properly called.

```
anz=$#
counter=1
if [ $(($# % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then
    for para in $@; do
        pos1=$counter
        pos2=$(($counter+1))
        echo $pos1=$pos2
        counter=$(($counter+2))
        if [ $counter = $(($# + 1)) ]; then
            exit 0
        fi
    done
fi
```

And i don´t have any information in my mind to do it 
Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Look for `bash arguments` (that's what "parameters" are called in bash). I'm confident you'll find all of the information you'll need.

Comment: @Tikorz better update question than to add a comment, i'm writting an answer to demonstrate how arrays can be used to take arguments 2 by 2

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul i did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following demonstrates functionnalities see bash manual `man bash`, for reference

```
#!/bin/bash

(( $#%2==0 )) || {
    echo "usage: $0 para1 para2 [para3 para4] ..."
    exit 1
}

# either using array
args=( "$@" )
for (( i=0;i<$#;i+=2 )); do
    echo "${args[i]} = ${args[i+1]}"
done

# or consuming arguments
while (( $#>0 )); do
    echo "$1 = $2"
    shift 2
done

# otherwise because printf has loop, just
printf "%s = %s\n" "$@"
```

Comment: ./test1.sh: line 21: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./test1.sh: line 22: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I get this

Comment: typo (`"` missing) is fixed

Comment: copy-paste answer, will not work as expected, this is to understand how it can work

Comment: If i hit only ./test1.sh (my bash file) then it put only a = out and if i put after ./test1.sh para1 para2 [ para3 para4 ] then it give usage: ./test1.sh para1 para2 [para3 para4] ... out

Comment: read my previous comment, and code comments there are three different solutions but you have to choose one

Answer (score 0):

./test1.sh para1 para2 [ para3 para4 ] # if i type this in terminal

the output is this :

```
 para1 = para2
 [ = para3
 para4 ] =
```

i use this code from you

```
args=( "$@" )
for (( i=0;i<$#;i+=2 )); do
echo "${args[i]} = ${args[i+1]}"
done
```